# Trouble deploying MERN Stack APP to Render

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern, vercel, render.com

I tried deploying my MERN stack app Backend using Vercel and Render.com. On Vercel it says build sucessful but when I test the site it just doesnt work but there is no log or anything to tell you what is going on.  On render I have had the most luck on clues of what may be going on: Whenever it gets to the part in the build where it does "npm start" is says there is no nodemon but I actually do have a nodemon. Why is this? Here is my package.json:

```
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
```

Here are the paramters I have entered into render project settings:

Build command: npm install

Start Command: npm start

Here are the environment variables added (not the exact ones of course):

JWT_SECRET=string

MONGO_URL= mongodb+srv://user:PASSWORD@cluster0.vz2veml.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority

NODE_VERSION=18.14.2

Here is the build Log section in render when it fails:

Jun 11 05:23:46 PM  ==> Using Node version 18.14.2 via environment variable NODE_VERSION

Jun 11 05:23:46 PM  ==> Docs on specifying a Node version: https://render.com/docs/node-version

Jun 11 05:23:46 PM  ==> Starting service with 'npm start'

Jun 11 05:23:50 PM

Jun 11 05:23:50 PM  > server@1.0.0 start

Jun 11 05:23:50 PM  > nodemon index.js

Jun 11 05:23:50 PM

Jun 11 05:23:50 PM  sh: 1: nodemon: not found

Here is my cors in the index.js in the Backend:

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import cors from "cors";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import multer from "multer";
import helmet from "helmet";
import morgan from "morgan";
import path from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
import authRoutes from "./routes/auth.js";
import userRoutes from "./routes/users.js";
import postRoutes from "./routes/posts.js";
import { register } from "./controllers/auth.js";
import { createPost } from "./controllers/posts.js";
import { verifyToken } from "./middleware/auth.js";
import User from "./models/User.js";
import Post from "./models/Post.js";
import { users, posts } from "./data/index.js";

/* CONFIGURATIONS */
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);
dotenv.config();
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(helmet.crossOriginResourcePolicy({ policy: "cross-origin" }));
app.use(morgan("common"));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));

// Add CORS middleware and specify the frontend URL and localhost:3001 as options
const corsOptions = {
  origin: ["https://.xxxxxxxxxxxonrender.com", "http://localhost:3001"],
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use("/assets", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public/assets")));

/* FILE STORAGE */
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "public/assets");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  },
});
const upload = multer({ storage });

/* ROUTES WITH FILES */
app.post("/auth/register", upload.single("picture"), register);
app.post("/posts", verifyToken, upload.single("picture"), createPost);

/* ROUTES */
app.use("/auth", authRoutes);
app.use("/users", userRoutes);
app.use("/posts", postRoutes);

/* MONGOOSE SETUP */
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 6001;
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server Port: ${PORT}`));

    /* ADD DATA ONE TIME */
    //User.insertMany(users);
    //Post.insertMany(posts);
  })
  .catch((error) => console.log(`${error} did not connect`));
```

I have tried changing the paramaters over and over. I also installed nodemon as -g to my backend again although I already had it.